# C pointers: copy strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to copy the string contained in

```
char *src
```

into

```
char *dst
```

this is my function but doesn't compile

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dst, char *src, size_t len)
{
    char *temp = dst;

    char *p = dst;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (p = dst; i < len; p += 1)
    {
        *p = *(src + p);
        i += 1;
    }

    return *temp;
}
```

Comment: `*p = *(src + p);` shouldn't that be something among the lines of `*p = *(src + i);` instead?

Comment: yes it does compile but doesn't do what expected

Comment: what is the purpose of `p < src` ?

Comment: If it does not compile you should include the error message in the question.

Comment: The behavior of `p < src` is not defined by the C standard. You should not compare pointers from different objects for order. (Pointers may be compared for equality. Pointers within one object, such as an array or structure, may be compared for order.) Nor is there any reason to do such a comparison; the function is apparently designed to copy `len` characters, so only `len` is needed to control the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overdoing it.

You probably want this:

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dst, char *src, size_t len)
{
   while (len > 0)
   {
     *dst++ = *src++;
     len--;
   }

   return dst - len;
}
```

This is totally wrong

```
return *temp;
```

`*temp` is a `char` an not a pointer so `return temp;` would be correct.

BTW: strictly speaking we are not copying a string as a string in C is a NUL terminated sequence of chars. Here we are just copying `len` bytes.

Comment: my function needs to return the dst string

Comment: I think i should do 

    return dst; (is it correct?)

Comment: @cucklordv4 not quite, consider what the `++` is doing to `dst`.

Comment: ok so dst must be the adress of the first char ? so i need to return *dst ?

Comment: @cucklordv4 no, you need to return the value that `dest` had _before_ we enter the `while` loop. After the `while` loop, `dst` points _after_ the last copied byte. Hint: use temporary variable. And BTW `*dst` is not a pointer but a `char`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Pointer arithmetic with `len` will work as well.

Comment: @GovindParmar sure, there are different possibilities.

Comment: I have edited my question by I get this incompatible integer to pointer conversion
      returning 'char' from a function with result type 'char *';
      remove * [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: @cucklordv4 the warnign contains the solution and so does my updated answer.

Comment: but then i am returning the address of that char

Answer (score 2):

You are really close; your error is on this line:

```
*p = *(src + p);
```

Think about why you are dereferencing `*(src + p)`... remember, where is the memory location of the character you're trying to copy?

Also your function should either return `void` since there's no `return` statement anywhere, or return `dst`. Also, you don't need `p < src` in your loop guard.

Comment: why I don't need p < src ?

Comment: @cucklordv4 other question: why do _you_ think you need it?

Comment: Rather than changing the type to return `void`, the intent may have been that the function returns the destination, as the standard `strncpy` does.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Updated my answer.